PCB Coil Inductance Calculation
I am designing (noob electronics engineer) an inductive position sensor using Renesas IPS2200 (https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/ips2200-datasheet).
The sensor requires a PCB coil (L in the image below, between pins TX1 and TX2) for the measurements. As stated in the datasheet, for the device to work between the supported frequencies (1.7 MHz < f < 5.8 MHz), the PCB coil must have a determined inductance (L) value calculated using the formula:
$$f_{Tx} = \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{L \frac{C_{Tx}}{2}}}$$

Having designed this coil using with rectangular shape (knowing all parameters of the PCB manufacturer capabilities):

Considering that I can choose whatever value of C that I need, then I have to determine L for the frequency to be in range.

How can I determine the value of L practically or by software?

Thanks in advance.

SaturnPCB Can calculate rectangular PCB inductors with reasonable accuracy.

@LiorBilia Thanks, nice software. Is there any difference if I calculate the coil L as a trace of l length (very long) using the Conductor Impedance tab (Lo) vs using the Planar Inductors tab?
